# How to convert mp3 to wav without losing metadata?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, wav

How can I convert an mp3 file to wav without losing metadata in ffmpeg?

This happens whether I convert from mp3 or if I'm re-encoding a wav file, it doesn't make a difference.

I tried adding `-map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3` to my command but to no avail. Please help.

(using `ffmpeg-4.1-win64-static`)

Comment: FFmpeg does not, at present, support writing id3 tags in WAVs.

Comment: WAV doesn't support ID3 tags at all - only RIFF tags are allowed, embedding ID3 tags inside them is not portable.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck it worked in Foobar though, will it cause mp3-players with old firmware to crash due to a header discrepancy? (Not that I know what that is though (just heard that somewhere))

Comment: [BWAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_Wave_Format) or RF64 *might* be able to do something close to what you need [I'm no codec expert so this is a bit of a guess, based on my DAW's export info abilities.]

Comment: @Emdosis Outdated MP3 Players will most likely either not play WAV at all or ignore RIFF tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned, it's currently not possible with FFmpeg, as there is no standard method for saving ID3(v2) metadata in WAV files. There are indeed some non-standard ways to save ID3 tags in RIFF chunks. You can find a bit [more info here](https://github.com/Borewit/music-metadata/wiki/RIFF-WAVE).

There is an [open ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7579) for FFmpeg that I created for another user who had a similar problem.